# Resources for reviewing and learning from real-world projects?

Tags: postmortem

I'm currently studying the "death march" phenomenon, as it relates to project management.

(From my understanding, the term "death march" refers to a project which is evidently at high risk of failure, but which management continue to drive forward, resulting in overwork, loss of motivation among participants, etc.)

Can you suggest any sources for "post-mortem" information regarding projects which might fit this criteria?

Or more generally, are there any resources (offline and/or online) for historical/biographical information about various projects that have been undertaken, how they were planned, how execution went, and what the results were?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are any number of resources online. Just do a quick search with specific keywords, primarily around the types of failure or projects you're interested in.

Have you read "Death March" by Edward Yourdon?

Two more good sources would be the IJPM (Int'l Journal of PM) from IPMA or PM Journal from PMI. Both provide a number of academic articles and case studies with these types of projects.